# Making an auction script start and stop auctions at specific times.

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am building a simple auction application. I need auctions to start and end at certain times. Should the page that displays the open auctions just run a query to find all auctions where current time is after the start time and before the end time? Or would it bet better to have a script that sets a "active" column to True? If this is the case would I have to have some type of cronjob setup?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! However, your question is too open-ended to be answerable right now. You are asking us whether you "should" do X, but not telling us what your constraints or worries are. As an example, imagine if someone walked up to you on a street corner and asked you, "Should I cross the street now, or wait 30 minutes?" You would probably ask for more information about the guy's goals before answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No cron and no "active" column is required. Just list auctions using something like:

```
select *
from auctions
where
    start < now()
    and end > now()
```

When user is placing a bid use the following:

```
update auctions set
    bid = $bid,
    highest_bidder = $bidding_user_id
where
    id = $this_auction_id
    and start < now()
    and end > now()
    and bid < $bid
```

Then check if query has affected a row. If yes - bid is successful, current user is highest bidder. If no - bid is too low or auction has finished. You can figure out that later by fetching auction row again and checking bidder id.

Comment: And before starting be sure that you understand how to use php and mysql safely.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a "close_time" field in the mysql table with your auction. When you add the row, populate that field with a `time() + whatever` to set the close_time to represent some point in the future.

Then setup a script which runs a simple query:

```
'UPDATE auctions_table SET active = FALSE WHERE active = TRUE AND close_time <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()'
```

Save that query to a php page called something like `close_active_auctions.php` and set that up on a cron for once every 10 seconds or so (or however often you need).